# How to set a BETWEEN statement in var in querybuilder

Tags: javascript, sql, query-builder

I'm trying to set the default query on pageload for mystic100's querybuilder using a var i.e.:

```
var sql_import_export = 'name LIKE "%Johnny%" AND (category = 2 OR in_stock = 1)';

$('#builder-import_export').queryBuilder('setRulesFromSQL', sql_import_export);
```

Does anyone know the syntax for a BETWEEN sql statement?

Comment: Yeah, I think a couple people on here may know that syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I had included  in my application but didn't.  Adding this file fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

i think this is what you looking for.

```
column_name BETWEEN value1 AND value2;
```